# ASP.NET Login Controls and Layout Template

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I have an asp:Login and a  within that. I want to add a checkbox within that but everytime I do, I can't see it in the code behind.

```
<asp:Login id="LoginAuth" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        ....
        <asp:CheckBox ID="TermsCheckbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="AgreeTerms_OnChecked" />
```

Doing this in the code behind gives me an error:

```
  LoginAuth.TermsCheckbox.Checked = true or TermsCheckbox.Checked = true
```

It doesn't seem to see TermsCheckbox anywhere. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your control is in a LayoutTemplate, you need to use this:

```
CheckBox termsCheckBox = LoginAuth.FindControl("TermsCheckbox") as CheckBox;
termsCheckBox.Checked = true;
```